# Using Kerberos Service Ticket for Local HOST Service and Obtaining a Network Token in C++

Tags: windows, kerberos, windows-authentication, sspi

I have the following requirement: I have saved the Kerberos service ticket for the current computer's HOST service in the local computer cache. Now, I want my client/server program to use this service ticket to initiate requests against the local HOST service and obtain a usable network token. With this network token, I aim to call the CreateProcessAsUser function to start some programs. How can I achieve this using a series of calls to AcquireCredentialsHandle, InitializeSecurityContext, and AcceptSecurityContext functions? Please note that both the client and server parts of my program are integrated into the same program. If possible, could you provide me with a C++ code snippet to accomplish this?

If possible, could you provide me with a C++ code snippet to accomplish this?